# Need your help in finding my palindrome

Tags: c, string, palindrome

Need your help in finding a palindrome.

The problem in my palindrome is: when I put a sentence the test is not performed well because my program checks only the first letter and the last letter So this causes problems
With the first letter of sentences is worth to last letter but the second letter is not worth to the one before last letter.

If you can help me solve this I appreciate it
Thanks.

my code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char recursive_palindrome(const char st[], int first, int last )
{
if(st[first] != st[last])
{
    return(0);
}   
if(last-first<=1)
{
    return(1);
    return(recursive_palindrome(st, first+1,last+1));
}
}

int main()
{
char st[255];
printf("enter a string: \n");
gets(st);

if ( recursive_palindrome(st,0,strlen(st)-1))
{
    puts("yes\n");
}
else
{
    puts("No");
}
}
```

Comment: You should enable a higher warning level and look at the compiler warnings. In recursive_palindrome you would get one warning for unreachable code (third return) and a warning for reaching the end of the function without a return. Both are (not the only) errors you should correct.

Comment: Our help, your palindrome?

Comment: Does your question answered?

Answer (score 2):

```
if(last-first<=1)
{
    return(1);
    return(recursive_palindrome(st, first+1,last+1));
}
```

Should be modified into

```
if(last-first<=1)
{
    return(1);
}
return(recursive_palindrome(st, first+1,last-1));
```

Please note that your original `recursive_palindrome()` does not reach any return statement if `st[first] == st[last] && last-first > 1`. Compiler should have issued a warning about it.

Comment: Sorry but still it did not help even it ruined what was until now

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
return(recursive_palindrome(st, first+1,last+1))
```

should not be in the conditional block

```
if(last-first<=1) {
```

because you want to recurse if that branch is *not* taken.  Also, it should be:

```
    return(recursive_palindrome(st, first+1,last-1))
```

(first moves forwards, last moves backwards).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this code, I solved the issues which were:

1) This `if(first > last)` before `if(st[first] != st[last])` so you save extra call.
2) This fix:

```
if(st[first] != st[last])   
{   
    return(0);   
}
```

3) This calling was adding last+1 which is wrong!

```
return(recursive_palindrome(st, first+1,last-1));
```

---

The Code:

```
char recursive_palindrome(const char st[], int first, int last )
{
    if(first > last)
    {
        return(1);
    }

    if(st[first] != st[last])
    {
        return(0);
    }

    return(recursive_palindrome(st, first+1,last-1));
}

int main()
{
    char st[255];
    printf("enter a string: \n");
    gets(st);

    if ( recursive_palindrome(st,0,strlen(st)-1))
    {
        puts("yes\n");
    }
    else
    {
        puts("No");
    }

    return 0;
}
```